# Logging in proper order in Task Parallel Library scenario

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

My windows service written in C# retrieves thousands of employee communication details and accordingly sends out emails to them.

I have written the emailing sending part using `Parallel.Foreach()` block for every employee. I have a requirement to log the execution of code and values that I retrive from every employee in a (.txt) or (.log) file.

As I am using `Parallel.Foreach()`, I will not be able to control the order in which the values processed.

How do I make sure the every line of execution that I capture in a log file is logged in a proper order so that, it will be easy to read the log file for later use.

Please suggest.

Comment: Perform a post processing process to read, order and save. This will prevent re-writing your existing code. If this is not suitable, you may have to re-write using `Task.Factory.StartNew...` etc. and chain you tasks as required (this will of course be more complex).

Comment: By proper order do you mean by chronological order? BTW what logging library are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this would be to use PLINQ instead of `Parallel.ForEach()`. If you use `AsOrdered()`, you are guaranteed that the data the PLINQ query produces will be in the correct order.

Though I'm not sure if changing your code like this just for logging makes sense.

The code could look something like this (assuming `SendEmail()` returns the log):

```
var logs = users.AsParallel().AsOrdered()
                .Select(u => SendEmail(u));

foreach (var log in logs)
{
    AppendLog(log);
}
```